# Problems reading text file data in Java

Tags: java

I have this code:

```java
  BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userdetails.txt"));
     String str;
     ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     while ((str=br.readLine())!=null){
        String datavalue [] = str.split(",");
        String category = datavalue[0];
        String value = datavalue[1];
        stringList.add(category);
        stringList.add(value);
     }
     br.close();
```

it works when the variables category and value do not have a comma(,),however the values in the variable value does contain commas.Is there a way that I can split the index of the without using comma?

Comment: You will need to use a different separator for the values if the value themselves contain the comma which you use as your delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given bellow:

```
    BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("userdetails.txt"));
    String str;
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((str=br.readLine())!=null){
        int firstIndexOfComma = str.indexOf(',');
        String category = str.substring(0, firstIndexOfComma);
        String value = str.substring(firstIndexOfComma + 1);
        stringList.add(category);
        stringList.add(value);
        System.out.println(category+" "+value);
    }
    br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When data has ',' it is generally called CSV file. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) is fairly used library to handle it. The format looks simple, but it has it quirks. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) for some details

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
    String str = "category,vvvv,vvv";
    int i = str.indexOf(',');
    String category = str.substring(0, i);
    String value = str.substring(i + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

split() uses regex.
if the reader code works perfectly, do

```
str.split("\\,");
```

Answer (score -2):

Not 100% sure, but couldnt you just do 
`String datavalue [] = str.split("--");` 
or something?

sample file:

`x,y,z--123--Hello World`

output:

`"x,y,z",
"123",
"Hello World"`